# How to play a bump sound in PyGame when the player hits the edge of the window without having the sound to continually play?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to make an if statement in PyGame to have sound affect playing when the player hits the edge of the screen, but I'm apperently making a mistake in my if statement; in another word, I check the condition in a wrong way becasue I don't want my soud affect to continually play when the user is at the edge of the screen, I want the sound to play once when the player is at the edge. I also don't my player to silde off the screen.

I have made a vatiable that handles the playing command in a variable called 'bump_sound':

bump_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("bump.wav")

And this is what my if statement look like:

```
    # These if statements check to make sure the player won't slide off the screen.
    # They also check if the player hits the edge; if so, play the bump sound.

    if self.rect.x >= 650:
        self.rect.x = 650
        bump_sound.play()

    if self.rect.x >= 650:
        self.rect.x = 650
    
    if self.rect.x < 0:
        self.rect.x = 0
        bump_sound.play()

    if self.rect.y > 325:
        self.rect.y = 325
        bump_sound.play()

    if self.rect.y < 0:
        self.rect.y = 0
        bump_sound.play()
```

Thanksfully, the player won't slide off the screen; however, the sound keeps playing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `>` instead of `>=`:

```py
if self.rect.x > 650:
    self.rect.x = 650
    bump_sound.play()
```

---

Another way is to use Boolean variables. One that indicates if the player hits the edge and one that indicates if the player hit the edge in the previous frame. The sound is played only if the player touched the edge but did not hit it in the previous frame:

```py
def __init__(self):
    # [...]
    self.previous_hit = False
    self.hit = False
```

```py
def your_function(self):

    self.previous_hit = self.hit

    if self.rect.x >= 650:
        self.rect.x = 650
        self.hit = True

    if self.rect.x <= 0:
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.hit = True

    if self.rect.y >= 325:
        self.rect.y = 325
        self.hit = True

    if self.rect.y <= 0:
        self.rect.y = 0
        self.hit = True

    if self.hit and not self.previous_hit:
        bump_sound.play()
```